# amust either be declared abstract or implement abstract method implement

Tags: java, android

```
public interface NameUpdateListener{

        void onUpdate(int position,String name);
    }


package vahitd.com.customdialog;

import android.app.ListActivity;

/**
 * Created by vahitd on 11.02.2016.
 */
public class CustomDialogActivity extends ListActivity implements NameUpdateListener{


}
```

> class CustomDialogActivity must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method implement on onUpdate(int position,String name) in NameUpdateListener

what is it wrong? help me please

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the method `onUpdate()` in your `CustomDialogActivity` class:

```
public class CustomDialogActivity extends ListActivity implements NameUpdateListener{
    void onUpdate(int position, String name)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: @vahitdurmuş no problem! Glad I could help!